# JSP Tabs are not active When adding DIV tag to LI tag

Tags: jquery, html, jsp, html-lists

I have created tabs using bootstrap in JSP. First tab contains a select tag and based on the selected value some other tabs are displayed and some tabs are hidden.

Here is my code

```
<div class="navbar btn-navbar">
        <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
            <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                <li class="active"><a href="#datacollector" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                    <div id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#fromDB" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load Database</a></li> </div>
                    <div id="fromFile" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#fromFile" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load File</a></li> </div>
                    <div id="email" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#email" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load Email</a></li> </div>
                    <div id="webServices" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;">
                <li><a href="#webServices" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Load Web</a></li> </div>
                <li><a href="#datamap" target="main"
                    data-toggle="tab">Data Map</a></li>
                <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
            </ul>
<br> <br> <br>
            <div id="myTabContent" class="tab-content">
                <div class="tab-pane fade in active" id="datacollector">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="span8">
                                <form name="selectType" action="selectType"
                                    onsubmit="return validateForm()" target="#fromDB" method="get">
                                    <fieldset>
                                        <label class="control-label" for="dataloadType">Data
                                            load Type:</label> <select id="dataloadType" name="dataloadType">
                                            <option>Choose Data load Type</option>
                                            <option value="fromDB">From Database</option>
                                            <option value="fromFile">From File</option>
                                            <option value="email">E-mail</option>
                                            <option value="webServices">Web Services</option>
                                        </select>
                                        <p>
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                                        </p>
                                    </fieldset>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="fromDB">
                    <iframe src="GenericFileUpload.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="fromFile">
                    <iframe src="GenericDB.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="email">
                    <iframe src="EmailService.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="webServices">
                    <iframe src="WebService.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="datamap">
                    <iframe src="DataFieldMapping.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="schedule">
                    <iframe src="UploadConfiguration.jsp" width="1250" height="400"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

And my script is

```
<script>
$(function() {    

    $('#dataloadType').change(function(){
    $('.selectDataloadType').hide();
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    var value = $(this).val();
      $('#tabs').tabs('select',value);
    });
    });
</script>
```

And I have a problem here.

In the `<li>` tag 3 are using the DIV tag because those 3 are hidden and displayed based on SELECT value. Script is working fine and it will display only the tab which is based on the selected value. But the real problem is, the one which will be displaying is not a tab. **(The 3 LI tag using DIV are not displaying as tags)** It is showing as a Link only and I am not able to open that Tab. What should I do?

Its showing like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got its answer. Do not add `DIV` in `LI`. Instead, add the **id** and **class** to the **LI** itself

```
<div class="navbar btn-navbar">
            <div id="tabs" class="tabbable">
                <ul id="myTab" class="nav nav-tabs">
                    <li class="active"><a href="#datacollector" target="main"
                        data-toggle="tab">Data Collector</a></li>
                    <li id="fromDB" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromDatabase" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Database</a></li>
                    <li id="fromFile" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromFiles" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            File</a></li>
                    <li id="email" class="selectDataloadType" style="display: none;"><a
                        href="#fromEmail" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load
                            Email</a></li>
                    <li id="webServices" class="selectDataloadType"
                        style="display: none;"><a href="#fromWebServices"
                        target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data Load Web</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#datamap" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Data
                            Map</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#schedule" target="main" data-toggle="tab">Schedule</a></li>
                </ul>
```